# pythons opencv running out of frames when using webcam

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to set my opencv to make a heat map. I have it working for a set .mp4 file. However when i try to make it work using my webcam on a live feed it doesn't seem to like it. the problem it has is it says that the `"index is out of range"` fr the following lines of code:

```
make_video('./frames/', './output.avi')
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
```

The .py file is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import copy
from make_video import make_video
from progress.bar import Bar



def main():
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    background_subtractor = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
    length = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    bar = Bar('Processing Frames', max=length)

    print(length)
    short = length
    first_iteration_indicator = 1
    for i in range(0, short):

        print(i)

        ret, frame = capture.read()

        # If first frame
        if first_iteration_indicator == 1:

            first_frame = copy.deepcopy(frame)
            height, width = frame.shape[:2]
            accum_image = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
            first_iteration_indicator = 0
        else:

            filter = background_subtractor.apply(frame)  # remove the background
            cv2.imwrite('./frame.jpg', frame)
            cv2.imwrite('./diff-bkgnd-frame.jpg', filter)

            threshold = 2
            maxValue = 2
            ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(filter, threshold, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

            # add to the accumulated image
            accum_image = cv2.add(accum_image, th1)
            cv2.imwrite('./mask.jpg', accum_image)

            color_image_video = cv2.applyColorMap(accum_image, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)

            video_frame = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.7, color_image_video, 0.7, 0)

            name = "./frames/frame%d.jpg" % i
            cv2.imwrite(name, video_frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        bar.next()

    bar.finish()

    make_video('./frames/', './output.avi')

    color_image = cv2.applyColorMap(accum_image, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
    result_overlay = cv2.addWeighted(first_frame, 0.7, color_image, 0.7, 0)

    # save the final heatmap
    cv2.imwrite('diff-overlay.jpg', result_overlay)

    # cleanup
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in order to set it to the webcam i use `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` which causes the error above, however if i use a pre-saved .mp4 file like so capture = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4') it works fine.Any ideas?

Comment: When using your webcam with `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`; the line `length = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))` becomes `-1`. This causes it to skip the `for` loop entirely. Leading you to "index error" at `make_video('./frames/', './output.avi')`

Comment: your code contains no `images` variable, or any calls to `imread`. please make sure the traceback and code match. please review [mre]. -- if this is a bug with that "make_video" package, you need to submit a bug report to the author of that package

Comment: @JeruLuke does this mean that because its a live video it nt count the frames?

Comment: @kitchen800 Correct. "Real-time" video would be the right term

Comment: @JeruLuke are there alternatives I should use?

Comment: @kitchen800 I have to alter your code such that iteration through the frames is removed.

Comment: cool thanks, maybe i did this whole thing wrong because the whole thing is based on that iteration, comparing one frame to the last frame :(

Comment: @kitchen800 What is `make_video`? Is it a package that can be installed? or is it a custom function imported from another script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

When using your webcam with `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`; the line `length = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))` is not helpful. Because, when using a webcam `capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)` returns `-1.0`. And that means to say the number of frames does not apply when using webcam. It makes sense when using to read video, since it can find out the number of frames present in the video.

**Solution:**

I modified the existing code to use the webcam and removed the `for` loop. I tested this code without `make_video`. The results were as expected on analyzing them using `cv2.imshow` (uncomment them to see it for yourself).

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

background_subtractor = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()

threshold = 100
maxValue = 255

# for counting frames
i = 0
while True:
    i = i + 1
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    if frame is None:
        break
    
    fgMask = background_subtractor.apply(frame)
    ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(fgMask, threshold, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(th1,(11,11), 9)
    heat_map = cv2.applyColorMap(blur, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
    video_hm = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.7, heat_map, 0.7, 0)

    name = "./frames/frame%d.jpg" % i
    cv2.imwrite(name, video_hm)
    
    #cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    #cv2.imshow('FG Mask', fgMask)
    #cv2.imshow('Video OP', video_hm)
    #cv2.imshow('Blur', blur)
    
    keyboard = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if keyboard == 'q' or keyboard == 27:
        break

capture.release()
make_video('./frames/', './output.avi')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: i see exactly where you were coming from now. That makes alot of sense. thank you so much, i really appreciate the help, and learned a lot.